# Generic GDI+ Error Occurred QR Code

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, api

I get several generic gdi+ error code at times when there are lots of requests coming in. Most of the times there are no errors on this part tho.

I believe the error to be on this part

```
            string guidString = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            string dateNowString = DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyHHmmssfff");
            var localFilePath = @"c:\temp\" + dateNowString + ".png";

            //Create QrCode on local
            QrEncoder qrEncoder = new QrEncoder(ErrorCorrectionLevel.M);
            QrCode qrCode = qrEncoder.Encode(pass.Barcode);
            Renderer renderer = new Renderer(5, Brushes.Black, Brushes.White);
            renderer.CreateImageFile(qrCode.Matrix, localFilePath, ImageFormat.Png);
            /*using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(localFilePath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    renderer.WriteToStream(qrCode.Matrix, ms, ImageFormat.Png);
                }
            }*/

            //Upload locally saved QR image to AWS S3
            string bucketName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["bucketName"].ToString();
            var s3Client = new S3(bucketName, guidString);
            string key = guidString + dateNowString + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FileFormatExtension"].ToString();
            qrCodeUrl = s3Client.UploadFile(localFilePath, key);

            //Delete QrCode image on local
            if (File.Exists(localFilePath))
            {
                File.Delete(localFilePath);
            }

            //Save QrCode Url to BoardingPass Table
            pass.QrCodeUrl = qrCodeUrl;
            data.SaveChanges();
```

This is called by several threads ( 1 call = 1 thread, I am applying a task to run these threads concurrently, a thread may call this part more than once)

here's the stacktrace

```
   at System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageCodecInfo encoder, EncoderParameters encoderParams)     at Gma.QrCodeNet.Encoding.Windows.Controls.Renderer.CreateImageFile(BitMatrix matrix, String fileName, ImageFormat imageFormat)     at <redacted>API.Helpers.BoardingPassHelper.GenerateQRCode(BoardingPassRequest request) in <redacted>.API\Helpers\BoardingPassHelper.cs:line 972     at BCSBoardingPass.API.Controllers.API.BoardingPassController.GenerateMultiPaxBoardingPass(MBPRequest mbpRequest, Int32 requestIndex, Boolean isMbp) in <redacted>controllers\API\BoardingPassController.cs:line 615
```

Comment: Could it be that two threads are trying to create the same file? Try changing file name to something with a running counter instead of date suffix just to test.

Answer (score 2):

We had this kind of random error using the version v 0.3 of the library, in a multithread environment. We did not manage to fix this random behavior, but we noticed that since we switched image format from PNG to JPEG, we didn't get the error anymore.